# POST 2 files from MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i pass 2 word documents to controller from MVC view.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadDocument", "Application", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file1">Please select application document (word file) </label>
            <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" class="form-control" />

            <label for="file2">Please select support document ( word file )</label>
            <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
 }
```

And in controller

```
    public ActionResult UploadDocument(int Id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
    }
```

But i want to get file1 and file2 differently inside the controller so i can save it to different places. I have to save File1 in one place and file2 in another place. So how can i make sure i get files seperatly?

Comment: Either give them both a unique name or loop through them in the controller

Comment: But how can i know which file is the first one and which is second one ? Is any guarantee that files wil be in order

Answer (score 2):

Give them a separate unique name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadDocument", "Application", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file1">Please select application document (word file) </label>
            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" class="form-control" />

            <label for="file2">Please select support document ( word file )</label>
            <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadDocument(int Id, HttpPostedFileBase file1, HttpPostedFileBase file2)
{
    // do something with the files
}
```

---

---

Even better would be to use strongly typed views with viewmodels:

```
public class FileUploadViewModel {
    HttpPostedFileBase file1 { get; set; }
    HttpPostedFileBase file2 { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.FileUploadViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadDocument", "Application", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file1">Please select application document (word file) </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file1, null, new { type = "file", id = "file1", @class = "form-control" })

            <label for="file2">Please select support document ( word file )</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file2, null, new { type = "file", id = "file2", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    }
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadDocument(int Id, FileUploadViewModel model)
{
    // do something with the files
    if(model.file1 != null && model.file1.ContentLength > 0) {
        // save first file
    }
    // etc.
}
```